# How to simultaneously count and select with where in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `user` and `group` and also a `usergroup` as a link table which contains which users exist in a group.

To select the groups that a particular user is in, I can just do

```
SELECT * 
FROM usergroup 
INNER JOIN user 
ON user.id = group.user_id 
WHERE user.id = ?
```

To get the list of `usergroup` records that contain link to `user`

But how to also simultaneously get the number of other users in the same `group`?

While selecting the `group` info, I tried this

```
SELECT group.*, count(usergroup.*) group_count 
FROM usergroup 
INNER JOIN user 
ON user.id = group.user_id 
WHERE user.id = ?
```

but it always counts `1` (Probably because of the `WHERE user.id` filter)

Comment: Your requirement is unclear to me.  Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to select from `user` and `usergroup` tables to "find the list of groups" a particular user is in. Also simultaneously, I need to count the total users in each group along with it. A user can be in multiple groups.

Comment: It would be a lot quicker if you provide sample data and expected output as text.

Comment: Your second query is invalid. There is no `group` table in the FROM clause to select `group.*`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the size of groups that user 1 is in, then you can do:

```
select ug.group_id, count(*) as num_users
from usergroups ug 
group by ug.group_id
having sum( ug.user_id = 1 ) > 0;  -- has user 1
```

Comment: @P.Salmon . . . That's because I didn't want it.  Alas, I only removed half of it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a correlated sub query

```
drop table if exists u,ug;
create table u(id int);
create table ug (gid int,uid int);

insert into u values
(1),(2),(3);

insert into ug values
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),
(2,2),(2,3),
(3,3);

select u.*,ug.gid,(select count(*) - 1 from ug ug1 where ug1.gid = ug.gid) others
from u
join ug on ug.uid = u.id;

+------+------+--------+
| id   | gid  | others |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 |    1 |      2 |
|    2 |    1 |      2 |
|    3 |    1 |      2 |
|    2 |    2 |      1 |
|    3 |    2 |      1 |
|    3 |    3 |      0 |
+------+------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select group_id from usergroup where user_id = 1
```

returns all the groups where `user_id = 1` belongs to.
So you can use it in this query:

```
select group_id, count(*) - 1 otherusers
from usergroup
where group_id in (
  select group_id from usergroup where user_id = 1
)
group by group_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qU8pAk1YtmaSCX4gBvmCqV/0)